# I need to prove that the next proposition about integral is false

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f$ is integrable in $\mathbb{R}$ for all $\varepsilon >0$, exists $\delta >0$ such that $\vert f(x) \vert < \epsilon$ for almost everything $x$ with $\vert x \vert \geq \delta$. I have to prove that this proposition is false

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please show your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) to know how to ask a good question on this website. (Please take note that this website does **not** do your homework for you)

Answer (score 3):

Consider a sequence of "steps" of height $n$ and width $1/n^3$, i.e.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{for} & x\in (1, 1+1/1^3)\\
2 & \text{for} & x\in (2, 2 + 1/2^3)\\
3 & \text{for} & x\in (3, 3 + 1/3^3)\\
\dots\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

(In fact you can use this idea and a partition of unity to produce such a counterexample of class $C^\infty$).